# Using Glide to correct image orientation

Tags: android, image, bitmap, android-glide, google-vision

I am using Glide right now to load images from the gallery to an ImageView. 
Images from the gallery come rotated even if they are portrait. I am trying to pass these images into both an ocr library and the imageview.
Using glide, I was able to correct the orientation for the Imageview. However, how do I correct the orientation of the bitmap I am passing to the ocr library.

I would prefer to not use ExifIntefaces or Exif in general simply because I have been trying them for the past week and they don't work well with my code.

I would prefer to continue using Glide since it does correct orientation of the image loaded into the Imageview.

Is there anyway to get the image(with the corrected orientation) from the ImageView and save it as a bitmap?

Comment: A workaround is to set image using glide into an ImageView and then use 

`Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();`